# Dapper must declare Must declare the scalar variable "@pDBMode"

Tags: c#, asp.net

Three calls GetDetailData，but only one "BOML" call when error Must declare the scalar variable "@pDBMode", other call not error

```
string SQLStr = "Exec PR_SPSA03_Qry @pDBMode, @pDBKind, @pCompNo, @pProdNo, @pflow, @pSeq "
```

Add space "@pDBMode ," , after not error.

What is the reason?

```cs
switch (DBKind)
{
    case "BOML":
        bls = GetDetailData<BOMDTO>(DBKind, ProdNo, ref boms, ref Msg);
        if (bls)
        {
            HF_BData.Set("BOML", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(boms));
            grid_BOM.DataSource = boms;
            grid_BOM.DataBind();
        }
        break;
    case "PDML":
        bls = GetDetailData<PDMDTO>(DBKind, ProdNo, ref pdms, ref Msg);
        if (bls)
        {
            HF_BData.Set("PDML", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pdms));
            grid_PDM.DataSource = pdms;
            grid_PDM.DataBind();
        }
        break;
    case "PDFL":
        bls = GetDetailData<PDFDTO>(DBKind, ProdNo, ref pdfs, ref Msg);
        if (bls)
        {
            HF_BData.Set("PDFL", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pdfs));
            grid_PDF.DataSource = pdfs;
            grid_PDF.DataBind();
        }
        break;
}


private bool GetDetailData<T>(string DBKind, string ProdNo, ref List<T> Data, ref string Msg)
{
    string SQLStr = "Exec PR_SPSA03_Qry @pDBMode, @pDBKind, @pCompNo, @pProdNo, @pflow, @pSeq ";
    Function fn = new Function();
    DynamicParameters dynParams = new DynamicParameters();
    dynParams.Add("@pDBMode", "B");
    dynParams.Add("@pDBKind", DBKind);
    dynParams.Add("@pCompNo", Session["CompNo"].ToString());
    dynParams.Add("@pProdNo", ProdNo);
    dynParams.Add("@pflow", "");
    dynParams.Add("@pSeq", "");
    bool bls = fn.GetData<T>("SPS", SQLStr, dynParams, ref Data, ref Msg);
    return bls;
}


public bool GetData<T>(string ConStr, string SqlStr, DynamicParameters parameters, ref List<T> ReturnData, ref string Msg)
{
    bool bls = false;
    ConStr = GetConStr(ConStr);
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
        {
            conn.Open();
            ReturnData = conn.Query<T>(SqlStr, parameters).ToList();
        }
        bls = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Msg = ex.Message;
    }
    return bls;
}
```

Add spapec "@pDBMode ," , after not error.

What is the reason?

Look SQL profiler:

#### Not OK check

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNVDB.png)

#### OK, call check

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1lOX.png)

Comment: Check you stored procedure: `PR_SPSA03_Qry` and look if the parameter `pDBMode` matches what you are sending from `Dapper`.

Comment: @RahulSharma pDMBode check "B"

Comment: So change it to `pDBMode`

Comment: This is close to incomprehensible. Are you using [machine translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Translate)? Can you [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78151639/edit) it? (But *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today.)

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78151639/edit) (it covers program input and program output as well). Thanks in advance.